# Simple (E1 AND E2) OR (E3 AND E4)  expression in QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl

How do I express in QueryDSL where clause in form:

```
 WHERE (E1 AND E2) OR (E3 AND E4)
```

E1..E4 are arbitrary boolean expressions. The point is to have a query started within parenthesis, thus (E1 AND E2).

Comment: did you find what you where looking?

Answer (score 11):

```
where(e1.and(e2).or(e3.and(e4)))
```

Comment: Its true that this is equivalent logical formula as above, but not the same. What if I want to generate an SQL statement that is starting with parenthesis, although its logically equivalent to formula without them?

Comment: Querydsl guarantees that expressions are serialized in the correct way to SQL, so you needn't worry about paranthesis

Comment: "I don't need to worry" sounds a bit tricky for me. I never know if `where(e1.or(e2).and(e3))` means `(e1 or e2) and e3)` or `e1 or (e2 and e3)`. I was really surprised that `where(e1.or(e2).and(e3.or(e4)))` produced `(e1 or e2) and (e3 or e4)` which I actually wanted. But how did the first OR happen to be in parenthesis? Based on what? Does `...and(e3.or(e4))` makes any difference to `...and(e3).or(e4)` then? We generally review our queries in log, but I'd love to find something more concrete about this serialization.

Comment: @TimoWestkämper Yes, it does help. I also found BooleanBuilder in the meantime - which is answer to anything more complicated I guess. First I have to say, that I work with Querydsl around 4 months - it is one of the best libs I've ever encountered (usability, easy adoption, ...) - but the whole domain has inherent complexity. Sometimes I want to use javadoc on "where", but since it is generated, it doesn't help (understandably). I couldn't find exact explanation what x1.or.x2.or.x3.and.x4.whateveroperation.x5 does. However, Timo, you do a great job on any forum I saw. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TimoWestkämper i am having problems when I do that. Thru my debugger, the generated jpa QL is shown as "a and b or c and d". i want "(a and b) or (c and d)" parenthesis is missing. QueryDSL 3.6.3.